# How can I monitor and log the connections to my phone's wireless hotspot?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, logging

I'm sure the phone will be logging all connections and connection attempts when it is used to set up a wireless hotspot - my question is how can I view these logs?

If the default setting is not to log connections - is there a way I can turn it on or an app I can download?

Answer (score 1):

On a rooted phone with super user terminal client like ROM Toolbox Lite(from play store) you can check connected clients using netstat

```
netstat -ntu | grep ESTAB | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Checks on ESTABLISHED connections instead of all connections, and displays the connections count for each IP.